# IIS7 application pool identity problem

Tags: .net, iis-7

i'm having a problem with an MVC2 app im trying to deploy.
my app uses the windowsidentity.current.user.name for a number of data calls.  However, when i've deployed this to iis7 windows server 2008, the username and domain its passing from windowsidentity is the application pool identity.

i'm new to iis7 and never had this problem before in earlier versions so i assume its something i've configured wrong.  can some assist please?

Ideally i need the application to obtain the current users windowsidentity not the application pool.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What were you expecting it to be?

If you want it to be the name of the domain user accessing the page, you could either enable impersonation, or access the name through HttpContext.Current.User.Name.